# C#. How to open a folder in list view by double click

Tags: c#

I have started learning C# recently. Presently am working on creating "Windows Explorer".

Actual requirement is as follows

In list View Double Click function.

When I click on a folder in list view, it should display the files which are present in the folder in list view , but as per my code its being opened in another window.

Below is the code. Requesting for your help & guidance

```
alert(false);

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace New_Demo
{

    public partial class WindowsExplorer : Form
    {
        string SelectedPath = string.Empty;
        double size;
        string filelength;
        Login formPopup;
        private FileAttributes attr;


        public WindowsExplorer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateTreeView();
        }

        private void PopulateTreeView()
        {
            TreeNode rootNode;
            {
                DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\4076\Desktop\");

                if (info.Exists)
                {
                    rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
                    rootNode.Tag = info;
                    GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
                    treeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                    LoadFiles(info.FullName, rootNode);
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a path");
            }
        }


        private void LoadFiles(string dir, TreeNode td)
        {
            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*");
            // Loop through them to see files  
            foreach (string file in Files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                TreeNode tds = td.Nodes.Add(fi.Name);
                tds.Tag = fi.FullName;
                tds.StateImageIndex = 1;
                //UpdateProgress();
            }
        }
        private void GetDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] subDirs, TreeNode nodeToAddTo)
        {
            TreeNode aNode;
            DirectoryInfo[] subSubDirs;
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in subDirs)
            {
                aNode = new TreeNode(subDir.Name, 0, 0);
                aNode.Tag = subDir;
                aNode.ImageKey = "folder";
                subSubDirs = subDir.GetDirectories();
                if (subSubDirs.Length != 0)
                {
                    GetDirectories(subSubDirs, aNode);
                }
                nodeToAddTo.Nodes.Add(aNode);
            }
        }

        private void treeView_NodeMouseClick_1(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
            listView.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeDirInfo.FullName.ToString()))
            {
                SelectedPath = nodeDirInfo.FullName.ToString();
            }
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
            ListViewItem item = null;
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in nodeDirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(dir.Name, 0);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]{new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File Folder"),
                           new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,dir.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};
                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView.Items.Add(item);
                item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
                item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            }

            foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                long B = 0, KB = 1024, MB = KB * 1024, GB = MB * 1024;
                string suffix = nameof(B);

                if (file.Length >= GB)
                {
                    size = Math.Round((double)file.Length / GB, 2);
                    suffix = nameof(GB);
                    filelength = size + " " + suffix;
                }
                else if (file.Length >= MB)
                {
                    size = Math.Round((double)file.Length / MB, 2);
                    suffix = nameof(MB);
                    filelength = size + " " + suffix;
                }
                else if (file.Length >= KB)
                {
                    size = Math.Round((double)file.Length / KB, 2);
                    suffix = nameof(KB);
                    filelength = size + " " + suffix;
                }
                item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, 1);
                subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]{ new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"),
                           new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString()),
                           new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item,filelength.ToString())};
                item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                listView.Items.Add(item);
            }
            listView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);         
        }

        private void listView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
            {
                item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
                item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            }
        }

        private void listView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text))
                {
                    string SelectedPath_Combine = @"" + SelectedPath + "\\" + listView.SelectedItems[0].Text + "";
                   FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"" + SelectedPath_Combine + "");
                    if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(SelectedPath_Combine);
                    }
                    else if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                    {
                       // What to code here to display the files which are present in the folder??

                    }                      
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: why don't you remove all items in list and then renew with new directory?

Comment: and if it's directory, you should not run eventhandler on listView_MouseDoubleClick

Comment: MouseDoubleclick always have one item if user click only leftbutton. so you need to check if first selected item is folder or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make three changes in the code to achieve what you want

1. Make PopulateTreeView method to take path argument from outside
2. If Directory info check is successful in above method, empty all nodes before adding new
3. Call PopulateTreeView with selectedCombine path

Here is updated code

```
private void PopulateTreeView(string path)
{
  TreeNode rootNode;
  {
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    if (info.Exists)
    {
      treeView.Nodes.Clear();
      rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
      rootNode.Tag = info;
      GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
      treeView.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
      LoadFiles(info.FullName, rootNode);
    }
    else
      MessageBox.Show("Please select a path");
  }
}


 private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

  if (listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text))
    {
      string SelectedPath_Combine = @"" + SelectedPath + "\\" + listView.SelectedItems[0].Text + "";
      FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"" + SelectedPath_Combine + "");
      if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory)
      {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(SelectedPath_Combine);
      }
      else if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
      {
        PopulateTreeView(SelectedPath_Combine);

      }
    }

  }
}
```